# NSUndoManager beginUndoGrouping appears to happen twice, when only called once?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, undo, nsundomanager

I have a popover that opens and closes.
When it opens, I call `-beginUndoGrouping` on my `NSUndoManager`.
When it closes, I call `-endUndoGrouping`.

If I view my undo stack after the fact, I see this:

> 0: endUndoGrouping
>   1: endUndoGrouping
>   2: beginUndoGrouping
>   3: beginUndoGrouping

Note that there are no actions added inbetween the popover opening and closing.  I assume the grouping stays around because there is a nested undo group?

But I searched everywhere, and I am 100% positive I am not creating the nested group myself.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)colorWellWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
   NSLog(@"HEYHEY");
   NSLog(@"GROUP BY EVENT?: %@", [[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupsByEvent] ? @"YES": @"NO");
   NSLog(@"GROUPING LEVEL: %ld", (long)[[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupingLevel]);
   [[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] beginUndoGrouping];
   NSLog(@"GROUP BY EVENT?: %@", [[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupsByEvent] ? @"YES": @"NO");
   NSLog(@"GROUPING LEVEL: %ld", (long)[[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupingLevel]);
}

- (void)colorWellDidClose:(NSNotification*)notification
{
   NSLog(@"GROUP BY EVENT?: %@", [[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupsByEvent] ? @"YES": @"NO");
   NSLog(@"GROUPING LEVEL: %ld", (long)[[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupingLevel]);
   [[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] endUndoGrouping];
   NSLog(@"GROUP BY EVENT?: %@", [[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupsByEvent] ? @"YES": @"NO");
   NSLog(@"GROUPING LEVEL: %ld", (long)[[[[self imageController] document] undoManager] groupingLevel]);
}
```

Here is the output when I reproduce:

> 2015-12-21 15:37:41.300 Snagit[18714:8416571] HEYHEY
>   2015-12-21 15:37:41.300 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUP BY EVENT?: YES
>   2015-12-21 15:37:41.300 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUPING LEVEL: 0
>   2015-12-21 15:37:41.301 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUP BY EVENT?: YES
>   2015-12-21 15:37:41.301 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUPING LEVEL: 2
>   2015-12-21 15:37:45.000 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUP BY EVENT?: YES
>   2015-12-21 15:37:45.000 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUPING LEVEL: 1
>   2015-12-21 15:37:45.001 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUP BY EVENT?: YES
>   2015-12-21 15:37:45.001 Snagit[18714:8416571] GROUPING LEVEL: 0

Based on this, it looks like when I call `-beginUndoGrouping`, it immediately pushes 2 "beginUndoGrouping" actions onto the stack.
It would appear that any action I add at this point will go into the **inner group**.

Then directly **before** I call `-endUndoGrouping`, it magically thinks that there is only one undo group, so I can only assume any actions added at this point would go into the **outer group**.
And then **after** the call it thinks that I am back at the bottom level, and will add actions **outside of the group**.

So my question is, why are two groups being pushed onto my undo stack when I am only calling `-beginUndoGrouping` once?  And how can I remove all of the groups from my undo stack if there are no actions inside of the group?  I believe this should happen automatically, but again, because there is a nested undo group inside of the outer group-- the outer group does not automatically resolve.

Comment: The undo manager also groups undo's. If you close the undo group in colorWellWillClose you probably will see level 2 and 1. What happens if you don't begin and end undo grouping?

Comment: If I do not begin/end grouping, then nothing is ever pushed onto the stack (assuming I am following the same reproduction steps, where I just open the popover and close it without adding any actions)

Comment: If I do not begin/end grouping, and add an action to the stack, it gets added with only a  "beginUndoGrouping" and no matching "endUndoGrouping".  This throws an exception when I try to undo

Comment: NSUndoManager 0xcea2d60 is in invalid state, must begin a group before registering undo.

Comment: Did you see this answer? [NSUndoManager : separate multiple changes in one run loop cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763716/nsundomanager-separate-multiple-changes-in-one-run-loop-cycle)